# Unable to run a QMediaPlayer based application

Tags: linux, qt, gstreamer

I've created a virtual machine with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr), then I've installed Qt 5.8. The arch is x64.

I've tried to execute the following example:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html, the result is the error:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for -
"org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

I've enabled the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 variable and seen that:

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamermediaplayer")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/user/QtWorkspace/bin/mediaservice" ...
Cannot load library /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.so: (/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/mediaservice/../../lib/libqgsttools_p.so.1: undefined symbol: _gst_value_list_type)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.so" : "Cannot load library /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.so: (/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/mediaservice/../../lib/libqgsttools_p.so.1: undefined symbol: _gst_value_list_type)"
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

What is the cause of the "libqgsttools_p.so.1: undefined symbol: _gst_value_list_type" error? Why this mismatch? Is it possible that QtMultimedia does not support GStreamer 1.0 (Trusty comes with GStreamer 1.2.4 installed)?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 comes with Qt 5.3 or 5.4 as far as I know. So gstreamer libs in that version of Ubuntu may be too old for the Qt 5.8 that you're trying to use.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu comes with pre-installed Qt SDK. I've installed it using the offline installer, without any control on plugins/backends. To better understand what's happening I've downloaded Qt sources and tried to run the "configure" script. It seems that both GStreamer 0.1 and GStreamer 1.0 are not recognized. I tried to install dev libraries for GStreamer 1.0 and nothing has changed. I think that's definitively a problem of compatibility

Comment: Well, can't go far only with the stuff from the installation CD/DVD image. Install software from the Ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt install qtbase-dev` (google packages you need). It's point is to be compatible with everything else from the repository.